# array parameter at wcf services

Tags: android, json, wcf

This my first post I hope you can help me =).... Well, I am new at web services development, and I am doing an android project using WCF services with visual studio2010.  So, I want to send a list of string(or other kind of objects), using the web services this what I have so far:

Here is my data contract

```
namespace Android.WebService
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Modelo
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "MSG")]
        public string Mensaje { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Con { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Here is my interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet( 
        BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate = "validarUsuario/?user={user}&pass={pass}")]
    string validarUsuario(String user, String pass);
}
```

and finally:

```
public class Service : IService
{

    public string Redirect(String metodo, String[] data) {

        clsGestor gestor = new clsGestor();

        return "AUN";
    }
}
```

And finally, i get this error

La operación 'Redirect' del contrato 'IService' tiene una variable de consulta llamada 'data' del tipo 'System.String[]', pero el tipo 'System.String[]' no lo puede convertir 'QueryStringConverter'. Las variables de los valores de consulta de UriTemplate deben tener tipos que 'QueryStringConverter' pueda convertir.

Sorry fot the language(spanish), but it is about QueryStringConverter, it says it  cant read System.String[]. thanks

Comment: whats the issue? Try it, come back if you have difficulty... :) You'll learn a lot more from it :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. in fact i did, and y get this error: La operación 'Redirect' del contrato 'IService' tiene una variable de consulta llamada 'data' del tipo 'System.String[]', pero el tipo 'System.String[]' no lo puede convertir 'QueryStringConverter'. Las variables de los valores de consulta de UriTemplate deben tener tipos que 'QueryStringConverter' pueda convertir, sorry for the language(spanish), but the error is that QueryStringConverter, and it cant read System.String[] types.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that your Service class does not implement your IService interface contract - your interface specifies two strings as parameters but your Service class has a string and then a string[] - this is probably why you have the error regarding System.String[] types. Make sure your Service implementation matches your interface service contract.